# how can I start a new input() instance after breaking the initial input() with EOF exception?

Tags: python-3.x, input, stdin

I need to take multiple line input from user - works with a while loop, but have an issue starting another input() as the EOF gets "passed" over to the new input()

I've tried using a combination of the sys stdin, and func() but, not sure why it's happening.

`while True:
    try:
        list = input()
    except EOFError:
        break
input('input2:')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Don't use `list` as a variable name. That is a reserved word in python.
2) You can catch a `KeyboardInterrupt` which will stop the loop after a `Ctrl + C` and `EOFError` which catches a `Ctrl + D`:

```
while True:
    try:
        list = input()
    except (EOFError, KeyboardInterrupt):
        break
input('input2:')
```

Alternatively you can prime your loop and let the loop exit on a set condition:

```
my_input = input()

while my_input: # Break if nothing was inputted
    print(f"Inputed: {my_input}")
    my_input = input()

input('input2:')
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the suggestion - looks like the KeyboardInterrupt is caught, but will still get passed into input('input2') hmm..

Comment: @Vvega what do you mean it will get passed to `input2`? The except catches the `KeyboardInterrupt` and will discard it unless a `raise` is added. What input are you using and what output do you expect?

Comment: when I do command+D  (i'm on macOS)  the interrupt will also break input('input2'). and so It will close before letting me actually input anything.

Comment: @Vvega for `Ctrl+D` then you are right it is `EOFError` which still works. See my update.

Comment: Thanks! seems the issue is with Pycharm, but compiled into an exec seems to be working now :D